# Jquery loading two times on MVC 5,Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

**_Layout.cshtml**
`

```
    <div class="container-fluid body-content">


        @RenderBody()
    
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/moment-with-locales.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/datatables.min.js")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    @RenderSection("popups", required: false)
```

`

**Index.cshtml**
`

```
@section scripts{
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/js-year-calendar@latest/dist/js-year-calendar.js"></script>


    <script src="https://unpkg.com/js-year-calendar@latest/locales/js-year-calendar.es.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/js-year-calendar@latest/dist/js-year-calendar.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`

**Rendered Html while running mvc**
`

```
  <script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/moment-with-locales.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/datatables.min.js"></script>

    
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/js-year-calendar@latest/dist/js-year-calendar.js"></script>


    <script src="https://unpkg.com/js-year-calendar@latest/locales/js-year-calendar.es.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/js-year-calendar@latest/dist/js-year-calendar.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`

If i remove second jquery import i get $ not defined error and  the calendar of that view isnt loading(im using (https://year-calendar.github.io/js-year-calendar/documentation)

But right now, calendar is loading, but when selecting a range of days i am getting this error

```
jquery-ui.min.js:6 
        
       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'empty')
```

tried removing jquery to only render it one time in view, but that isnt working

BundleConfig.cs

```
  public class BundleConfig
{

    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery-ui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui*"));

       
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/umd/popper.min.js",
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css",
                  "~/Content/datatables.min.css",
                  "~/Content/select2.min.css",
                  "~/Content/body.css"
                  ));
    }
}
```

}

im trying to emulate this example for js calendar website in my mvc view

https://codepen.io/Paul-DS/pen/EMWBYQ

Comment: Please show your BundleConfig.cs code. Path -App_Start>BundleConfig.cs

Comment: added bundleconfig.cs contents in original question @PawanLakhara

Comment: remove from index.cshtml <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: JS already loaded with   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery"). After above change if not working then both js file put on layout.cshtml and remove  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery").

Comment: already tried that, if i do that i get 'jquery-3.3.1.js:3827 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function' @PawanLakhara